# How to create background worker/service/SyncAdapter for force close app in react native to receive push notification from react-native-firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

Push notification using react-native-firebase(fcm) works great unless app is force stopped(swiped).
How to create a background service/ sync adapter/ or anything similar using react native that will run in background even when app is force stopped and will listen to push notification from fcm?
So when notification is received it will display the notification in notification tray.

Comment: while closing application you want to listen notification service, and it will display in notification tray. right?

Comment: have you create notification listener method for listen new notification?

Comment: I want to build a service that is deteched from main app and that will listen to notifications sent from fcm.